# How do I use the Boolean values returned by a Java method?

Tags: java, boolean, return

I have a method that sends a bunch of characters to another method that will return true or false if certain character are present.  Once this method evaluates all the character and returns true or false for each of them how do I use those true or false vales in another method?
I think I have the method sending one character at a time.  The Boolean method is not a boolean array.

```
    public void Parse(String phrase)
{
    // First find out how many words and store in numWords
    // Use "isDelim()" to determine delimiters versus words
    //
    // Create wordArr big enough to hold numWords Strings
    // Fill up wordArr with words found in "phrase" parameter


    int len = phrase.length();
    char[] SeperateString = new char[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        SeperateString[i] = phrase.charAt(i);
        isDelim(SeperateString[i]);
        System.out.println(SeperateString[i]);

  boolean isDelim(char c)
{


    {
        if (c == delims[0])
            return true;
        else if (c == delims[1])
            return true;

        else if (c == delims[2])
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    //Return true if c is one of the characters in the delims array, otherwise return false

}
```

Comment: post your code. Your question isn't clear.

Comment: do you send a `collection` of characters at once, or you send characters one by one? does the method return a `collection` of booleans or it returns booleans one by one?

Comment: Is the method returning an array of booleans or a single boolean?

Comment: You can't define a method (isDelim) inside another method (Parse).

Answer (score 2):

so your method is like this

```
boolean myMethod(String s) {
    // returns true or false somehow... doesn't matter how
}
```

you can do this later

```
boolean b = myMethod("some string");

someOtherMethod(b);
```

or even

```
someOtherMethod(myMethod("some string"));
```

Now if your method is returning lots of booleans, say one for each character, it would look more like this

```
boolean[] myMethod(String s) {
    // generates the booleans
}
```

You'd have to access them some other manner, perhaps like so:

```
String str = "some string";
boolean[] bools = myMethod(str);
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    someOtherMethod(bools[i]);
}
```

For more information on this you'd have to post your code.

In response to the posted code, here's what I would do

```
/**
 * Parse a string to get how many words it has
 * @param s the string to parse
 * @return the number of words in the string
 */
public int parse(String s) {
    int numWords = 1; // always at least one word, right?
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(isDelim(s.charAt(i)) numWords++;
    }
    return numWords;
}

private boolean isDelim(char c) {
    for(char d : delims) if(c == d) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: that's cheating.. you edited it after my question in the comment :)

Comment: @tolitius I wouldn't call it cheating. We interpretted the question differently the first time. That's all. I'm still curious how it warrants a down vote.

Comment: relax, I am kidding. we are all here to help / learn. if the need is satisfied, that's all that matters. [by the way, I am not the one down voting your answer]

Comment: And I voted it up to balance, as you took the effort to answer although the question asked was vague (or worse)

Comment: @Guillaume If the OP decides to update his question, I'd love to elaborate on it! :-)

Comment: @user973858 I added an update to my answer with a refactoring of your method. One thing I notice is that you're already taking advantage of your "using the output of one in another". You'll have to give further clarification of what you're trying to do for more help, because my understanding is your question is asking how to do something that you're already doing. So my question is - what do you want your code to do that it isn't already doing?

Comment: Thanks a lot!  My problem was figuring out what to do after isDilms evaluates each char as true or false.  I thought I had to somehow send 'true' or 'false' back to parse and then do another evaluation with an if true or if false statement.  But you can do it all in one line I see.  I tried it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you could be using String.split() instead.
You can use regex with it as well, so you can include your 3 different delimiters.
If you need the number of works still you can get the result's length.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Assuming delims is a character array, it would be safe to use this to generate the regex:

```
String regex = "[" + new String(delims) + "]";
String result = params.split(regex);
```

Comment: That's going to compile a regex pattern which is considerably more expensive than what he's looking to do.

Comment: If efficiency is a problem, then yes, a per-character method would be faster, but in most cases, the amount of overhead added by regex will not have noticeable effect on runtime. The big thing is that it cuts down on a large amount of code.